# XML Data - How To Access

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm running a curl request and it returns the below:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [exp_cid] => 0BqO
        )

    [REQUEST] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => RETURN
                    [subtype] => CALLBUR
                    [EXP_ExperianRef] => 
                    [success] => Y
                    [timestamp] => Mon, 10 Feb 2014 at 10:28 AM
                    [id] => 0BqO
                )

            [MB01] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [seq] => 01
                        )

                    [DATEOFTRANSACTION] => 20100901
                    [VRM] => MYREG 
                    [VINCONFIRMATIONFLAG] => 0
                    [ENGINECAPACITY] => 01360
                    [DOORPLAN] => 14
                    [DATEFIRSTREGISTERED] => 20041007
                    [YEAROFMANUFACTURE] => 2004
                    [SCRAPPED] => 0
                    [EXPORTED] => 0
                    [IMPORTED] => 0
                    [MAKE] => PEUGEOT
                    [MODEL] => 307 ENVY 90
                    [COLOUR] => BLACK
                    [TRANSMISSION] => MANUAL 5 GEARS
                    [ENGINENUMBER] => EE
                    [VINSERIALNUMBER] => VF
                    [DOORPLANLITERAL] => 5 DOOR HATCHBACK
                    [MVRISMAKECODE] => L1
                    [MVRISMODELCODE] => BJJ
                    [DTPMAKECODE] => L1
                    [DTPMODELCODE] => 892
                    [TRANSMISSIONCODE] => M
                    [GEARS] => 5
                    [FUEL] => PETROL
                    [CO2EMISSIONS] => 155
                    [USEDBEFORE1STREG] => 0
                    [IMPORTNONEU] => 0
                    [UKDATEFIRSTREGISTERED] => 20041007
                    [MAXPERMISSIBLEMASS] => 01639
                    [MAXNETPOWER] => 085
                    [MAXTRAILERWEIGHTBRAKED] => 01000
                    [MAXTRAILERWEIGHTUNBRAKED] => 00620
                    [SOUNDLVLSTATIONARY] => 079
                    [SOUNDLEVELENGINESPEED] => 03938
                    [SOUNDLVLDRIVEBY] => 71
                    [SEATINGCAPACITY] => 005
                    [MASSINSERVICE] => 000001245
                    [MAKEMODEL] => PEUGEOT 307 ENVY 90
                )

            [MB37] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [seq] => 01
                        )

                    [V5CDATACOUNT] => 02
                    [V5CDATAITEMS] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [DATE] => 20090825
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [DATE] => 20041007
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm struggiling to access the return, I've tried the following but it doesn't return anything:

```
foreach ($xml->REQUEST->MB01 as $requestData) {

echo $requestData;

}
```

My other problem is depending on the vehicle reg it will return different MB blocks, is there away to return them if they are returned.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the full code that I'm running, when it's ran all I get is < Does this mean anything?

```
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output[0]['REQUEST']['MB01']['DATEOFTRANSACTION'];
```

Cheers guys.

Comment: Well, you try to access array elements with an oo notation. That won't work, you should get an error. Try to access them in array notation: `$xml['REQUEST']['MB01']`.

Comment: thanks @arkascha, this doesn't return anything - am I missing something?

Comment: did you do print_r($xml) ?

Comment: Yes @SandeepKumar - could it be anything else?

Comment: Either you have a typo or you do not really have such variable `$xml` as you write here. An array is an array is an array. Period.

Comment: @arkascha yes, but objects are also used in print_r statement. And we cannot access sub-objects deeper using foreach loop (I faced this problem earlier). Just assign:

    $someVar = $xml->REQUEST->MB01;

Then do , foreach ($someVar as $requestData) { ... }

Comment: @SandeepKumar Sorry, I cannot follow there: the output (the OP wrote it is a print_r output) shows `$xml` is an array, not an object (the OP confirmed he dumped $xml). `print_r()` does not write "array" if the subject is not an array. In addition there is no reasons why one should not be able to use a deeper nested object member reference as subject of a foreach loop. But as said: according to what the OP wrote this is an array, not an object.

Comment: @arkascha oh yes, I'm sorry. I see its an Array, and thought Object.

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger, you should learn how to use one anyway. Very convenient to debug non trivial issues. It should help you to step through the code and check each single detail.

Answer (score 0):

The return is an array, not an object. Try this :

```
foreach ($xml['REQUEST']['MB01'] as $requestData) {

    if(is_array($requestData) {
        print_r($requestData);
    } else {
        echo $requestData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ncrocfer, this doesn't return anything neither... Am i missing something.

Comment: Strange.. What is the return of `print_r($xml)` ?

Comment: Nothing, I just get <